# Regex to remove hyphens and restrict to first 4 digits and then from 5-7

Tags: regex, soapui

I am new to Regex and I would like to remove the hyphen (-) in the resultset for the JSONPath query-

```
$.results[0].user.name.cell
```

The query returns - 0752-276-086 and I would like to then use regex to remove the hyphens and leave as 0752276086 and then in a second query restrict to the first 4 digits and then the from digits 5-7.

Comment: Why does it need to be regex? Why not simple string substitution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace what "/-/g" matches

   This matches all the "-"
2. Use "[/^.{4}/](https://regex101.com/r/cI5xO6/1)"

   This matches the first 4 characters
3. Use "[/(?<=^.{4}).{3}/](https://regex101.com/r/bN1qI3/1)"

   This matches the first 3 characters that have 4 characters behind